# Python OpenCV - Detect eyes and save

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, eye-detection

I am new to OpenCV. I need to detect the eyes using opencv and save them in a folder for further classification. I have written following script for the same:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
     ret, img = cap.read()
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
     count=1
     for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
         cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
         roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
         roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

         eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
         for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
             crop_img = roi_color[ey: ey + eh, ex: ex + ew]
             cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
             s="{0}.jpg"
             s1='/home/kushal/Pictures/Webcam/'+s.format(count)
             count=count+1
             cv2.imwrite(s1,crop_img)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
if k == 27:
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to save as many eye images as possible. But I am getting only 3-4 eye images saved. Is it possible to get one frame or one image per second? What should be the modification done in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `count=1` outside of `while-loop`.

```
count = 1
while True:
    pass
    #your code
```

And the indent of `cv2.imshow` is not that correct.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count=1

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            print(count)
            crop_img = roi_color[ey: ey + eh, ex: ex + ew]
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
            s1='tmp/{}.jpg'.format(count)
            count=count+1
            cv2.imwrite(s1,crop_img)

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the previous answer, you can also experiment changing the scaling factor of the haar-cascade sliding window.

By this time you might have figured there are false positives in your gallery i.e non-eye images detected as eyes by the haar-cascade. So I'd recommend trying D-lib as it can achieve more accurate results. You can try to crop the region of interest from the 68-facial landmark points provided by the d-lib library. For your [reference](http://dlib.net/face_detector.py.html).

Comment: Okay. I will try it too. Thanks for the suggestion :)